# convert string to array not working

Tags: c#, arrays, list, arraylist

Im running through a list and extracting the position value from each record

```
string allPositionsListed = "";
int lastRecord = volunteerAssignmentList.Count;
int currentRecord = 0;
foreach (Volunteer va in volunteerList)
{
  currentRecord++;
  if (currentRecord == lastRecord)
  {
      allPositionsListed += va.Position;
  }
  else
  {
     allPositionsListed += va.Position + ",";
  }
}

//allPositionsListed returns: "51000785,52012986"
```

I have written a query extracting all the records from the positionTable where position is found..
if I use

```
var allPositions = new string[] { "51000785", "52012986" };

List<PositionTable> positionList = (from p in DbContext.PositionList
                 where allPositions.Contains(p.Position)
                select p).ToList();
```

this returns the correct results...but as the allPositions values may be different how do I convert it to the necessary string array.
ive tried

```
var allPositions2 = allPositionsListed.ToArray();

but this returns 
[0]5
[1]1
[2]0
[3]0
[4]7
etc...

when I need 
[0]51000785
[1]52012986
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of generating a string from your initial data, you can go directly to an enumerable, something like this should work:

```
var allPositions = volunteerList
    .Select(v => v.Position)
    .ToList();
```

Which will allow you to now do this:

```
var positionList = (from p in DbContext.PositionList
                    where allPositions.Contains(p.Position)
                    select p)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `Split` method:

```
var allPositionsListed = "51000785,52012986";
var allPositions2 = allPositionsListed.Split(',');
```

allPositions2 will be:
allPositions2[0] -> "51000785"
allPositions2[1] -> "52012986"

---

If you see the KB, it says this about the output of the String#ToArray method

> An array that contains the elements from the input sequence.

So, it is working as expected (of course)! and you need to use the right method.

Comment: While your answer is correct, there's no need to even generate the string in the first place.

Comment: @DavidG, Yes, but I wanted to point exactly to where the problem is. Definitely the problem could be solved by using just the `contains` method but he wouldn't realize that he's calling the wrong method for the purpose.

Comment: Even your answer would ultimately lead to uing `Contains` too.

Comment: @DavidG, yes, and what's wrong with that. Read the title of the question again please, then decide how the answer should look like.

Comment: All I'm saaying is that there was no need to do this at all, it's a waste of resources.